# How to create object of a reified type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-extension, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I was trying to create an extension function to create object of view holder for recycler view adapter

```
inline fun <reified T: RecyclerView.ViewHolder> ViewGroup.createViewHolder(@LayoutRes res: Int): T {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(res, this, false)
    // return ViewHolder Object
}
```

How do I create an object of the type T that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder so that I can return from the function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A clean alternative solution is to pass the constructor explicitly. It won't even be more verbose, because the type parameter can be inferred and doesn't need to be specified any more. Use like this:

```
val viewHolder = my_view_group.create(::MyViewHolder, R.layout.my_layout)
```

Implement like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: RecyclerView.ViewHolder> ViewGroup.create(createHolder: (View) -> T, @LayoutRes res: Int): T {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val itemView = inflater.inflate(res, this, false)
    return createHolder(itemView)
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the constructor too with `::` (function reference)? I didn't know that, cool!

Answer (score 6):

This solution is pretty ugly, but I'm assuming that "theoretically" can work :

```
inline fun <reified T: RecyclerView.ViewHolder> ViewGroup.create(@LayoutRes res: Int): T {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(res, this, false)
        return T::class.java.getConstructor(View::class.java).newInstance(itemView)
    }
```

What the last line is doing is :
1. Get the constructor of `T` that matches `T(view: View)`
2. call `newInstance` on that constructor, passing it the view you inflated

Solution adapted from https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/generic-object-creation/1663/5

Simply call it via :

```
val viewHolder = my_view_group.create<MyViewHolder>(R.layout.my_layout)
```

Comment: I understand this is the possible solution, but would like to know this is a good way to create ViewHolder? Is reflection a good thing?

Comment: Well, reflection is never really good. Here, many things could happen, such as an update to the way ViewHolder are created (not with a View as parameter for example). I'm not convinced you'll gain much from calling this instead of a simple MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout
                        .my_layout, parent, false))

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question as stated but should be helpful to those arriving here wanting to get rid of `Thing(Foo::class.java, ...)` and use `Thing<Foo>(...)`.

All you need to do is add a reified `invoke` in a `companion object`.

**Before**

```
class Thing<E : Enum<E>>(cls: Class<E>, value: String? = null) : Iterable<E> {
    ...
}

val thing = Thing(Foo::class.java, ...)
```

**After**

```
class Thing<E : Enum<E>>(cls: Class<E>, value: String? = null) : Iterable<E> {
    ...
    companion object {
        // Lets us construct using Thing<Foo>(...) instead of Thing(Foo::class.java, ...)
        inline operator fun <reified T : Enum<T>> invoke(value: String? = null) = Thing(T::class.java, value)
    }
}

val thing = Thing<Foo>(...)
```